# How Many Disciples in Luke 10---70 or 72?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, gospel-of-luke, disciple

In Luke 10:1 (NAB), we have:

> After this the Lord appointed seventy[-two]* others whom he sent ahead of him in pairs to every town and place he intended to visit.

The gloss therein, indicated by the asterisk says:

> Seventy[-two]: important representatives of the Alexandrian and Caesarean text types read “seventy,” while other important Alexandrian texts and Western readings have “seventy-two.”

In the D-R (Luke 10:1), there are no brackets:

> And after these things the Lord appointed also other seventy-two: and he sent them two and two before his face into every city and place whither he himself was to come.

Can anyone explain the gloss a bit further, indicating how or why a difference in numbers appears between two versions of the Bibles? Undoubtedly, there is a *significance* to the exact number of disciples Our Lord sent out, but it will be difficult to infer if the exact number is not known.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the "gloss" is simple. Of the early manuscripts in the original language we have of this passage, some say "seventy" and some say "seventy-two". Different translators have made different choices about which version they consider most reliable and/or most original. Some believe that the difference is worth bringing to the attention of the reader, and so have included it in a footnote. Some don't believe it worth bringing to the attention of the reader. This may be because they consider only one set of manuscripts to be authoritative and disregard all others.

If "D-R" means "Douay–Rheims" then that version is a direct translation of the 4th century Latin Vulgate, and so does not take into account any original manuscripts. It simply renders into English the Vulgate Latin, and so would write whatever number appears in the Vulgate without comment or footnote.

It is not necessarily true that there is a *significance* to the number, where the interpretation of the passage is substantially changed. Perhaps if God had intended for the difference to be important he would have ensured that the correct number was preserved throughout all manuscripts.

Comment: How can the underlying Greek be translated into two different numbers? carelessness?

Comment: There are multiple Greek manuscript copies of the Gospel of Luke. Some say seventy and some say seventy-two.